# Зачем нужны virtual includes в bazel?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, build

Перехожу в VSCode к объявлению класса, а меня переносит не в оригинальный хедер, а в какую-то директорию `_virtual_includes`. Как я понимаю, это связано с билдом bazel. Можете объяснить, для чего эти виртуальные хедеры? И можно ли переходить к оригиналам?

Comment: Приводите пример проекта и настройки, при использовании которых читающие вопрос смогут воспроизвести заявленное поведение. Также не стоит путать Visual Studio Code с IDE Visual Studio.

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос про bazel и его `_virtual_includes` независимо от настроек проекта

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл плагин для VSCode, с помощью которого можно это побороть, - https://github.com/zaucy/vscode-symlink-follow.